# Consulta sql para eliminar de dos tablas a la vez, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas, Ad_TipoConsulta y Ad_consulta, un tipo de consulta tiene varias consultas, busco el script sql para eliminar tanto el tipo como las consultas que pertenecen a ese tipo.

```
DELETE Ad_TipoConsulta, Ad_Consultas FROM Ad_TipoConsulta 
JOIN Ad_Consultas ON Ad_Consultas.Sec_TipoConsulta = Ad_TipoConsulta.Sec_TipoConsulta
WHERE Ad_Consultas.Sec_TipoConsulta = 121;
```

Esta consulta genera error en la (,) que separa Ad_TipoConsulta, Ad_Consultas.

Comment: El "Join" debe ser ante el "Where", no? Me parece eso no tiene mucho sentido. Puedes muestra los dos tablas?

Comment: Que si te puedo mostrar las dos tablas?

Comment: Los miembros de los tablas - la estructura de esos. Es raro que "Ad_TipoConsultas" esta en dos lugares - en la "DELETE" seccion y tambien en la "FROM" seccion.

Comment: Que es el error, exactamente?

Comment: no marcaste la respuesta correcta >:(

Answer (score 5):

Para evitar ese tipo de consultas deberias configuarar la relación con la regla de eliminacion en cascada, asi cuando elimines un tipo de consulta el motor de base de datos se encargara solo de eliminar las consultas asociadas,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen si y coloco la relacion en Cascada, cuándo elimine un taller, se eliminarán todas las ordenes que pertenecen a ese taller.

sé que no es la respuesta que quieres ya que estas preguntando explicitamente por la query, pero es un camino válido para tomar.

Comment: Si es una solución pero me están solicitando hacerlo por código :(

Comment: intenta con esto `DELETE Ad_TipoConsulta FROM Ad_TipoConsulta Inner JOIN AdConsulta ON Ad_TipoConsulta.Sec_TipoConsulta= Ad_Consulta.Sec_TipoConsulta where Ad_TipoConsulta.Sec_TipoConsulta = 121`

Comment: Elimina únicamente el tipo de consulta.

Answer (score 5):

Se que es un poco tarde y probablemente ya resolviste, de todas formas respondo por si a alguien más le sirve :)

En SQL SERVER **no es posible** eliminar de dos tablas al mismo tiempo usando la sentencia `DELETE` (tengo entendido que en MySQL si se puede), al menos hasta SQL SERVER 2016: de acuerdo a la documentación (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) solo se puede especificar una tabla de *destino* para la eliminación.

Si no puedes configurar una regla de eliminación en cascada en la Clave Foránea como indica Bloodday (supongo que tiene una), la única vía que veo sería eliminar primero las consultas que tengan ese tipo y luego el tipo mismo, esto en dos operaciones separadas:

```
DELETE Ad_Consultas 
WHERE Sec_TipoConsulta= 121;

DELETE Ad_TipoConsulta
WHERE Sec_TipoConsulta= 121;
```

Y si existe posibilidad de que una de las eliminaciones falle, ambas deben ejecutarse en la misma transacción (con el debido control de errores) para evitar que esta se realice a medias (e.g. que elimine las consultas, pero no el tipo)

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres eliminar de las dos tablas en el mismo query debes usar un `INNER JOIN` , por ejemplo:

```
DELETE Ad_TipoConsulta, Ad_Consultas FROM Ad_TipoConsulta INNER JOIN Ad_Consultas
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que una manera de hacerlo es eliminar primero la tabla con la llave foranea y luego eliminar la tabla normal, por ejemplo algo así:

```html
DELETE 
  FROM Ad_TipoConsulta 
WHERE Ad_TipoConsulta.Sec_TipoConsulta = 

(SELECT Ad_Consultas.Sec_TipoConsulta 
  FROM Ad_Consultas 
WHERE Ad_Consultas.Sec_TipoConsulta = 121 
--Aqui pueden ir más validaciones 
)
```

Eso lo que haría es eliminar todas las filas de "Ad_TipoConsulta" que tengan en su llave foranea el valor del SELECT Ad_Consultas.Sec_TipoConsulta

Ya despues borras a Ad_Consultas si también es lo que deseas, haciendo algo así

```html
DELETE 
       FROM Ad_Consultas
WHERE Ad_Consultas.Sec_TipoConsulta = 121
```

Me funciono algo parecido cuando el SELECT traía solo una fila, no se si no funcione si es más de una

Answer (score 0):

a mi me funcionó esto...cree un procedimiento almacenado e hice las dos consultas de DELETE por separado en el mismo procedimiento almacenado. También creé el parámetro "@rus_idusr" de tipo "Int" que es el parametro que recibia el id en Visual Studio y eso hace que se eliminen los dos registros relacionados de las dos tablas diferentes.

Espero les sirva.

```
create procedure [dbo].[Eliminarusuarioo]
@rus_idusr Int

as
begin

delete from adm_rus_roles_usuarios where rus_idusr = @rus_idusr

begin
delete from adm_usr_usuarios where usr_id = @rus_idusr

end
end
GO
```