# ¿Cómo elimino los datos de cinco tablas en MySQL en un solo query?

Tags: mysql

Hice un sistema y me piden que se pueda eliminar con un botón, la información que guardaron, hice el query que muestra toda la información, pero al cambiarlo por delete, me marca error.:

```
SELECT * FROM operacion O
  JOIN declaracion_abonos DA 
ON O.id_operacion = DA.id_operacion
  JOIN declaracion_cargos DC
ON O.id_operacion = DC.id_operacion
  JOIN relacion_abonos_cargos RAC
ON DC.id_operacion = RAC.id_relacion
  JOIN grupo_relacion_abonos_cargos GRAC
ON RAC.id_grupo = GRAC.id_grupo
```

Los errores son:     Palabra clave inesperada. (near "JOIN" at position 27)
    Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "JOIN" at position 27)

Pero, entonces ¿cómo se hace?

Comment: Te dejo una pregunta de un usuario de la comunidad que te puede servir https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8693/consulta-sql-para-eliminar-de-dos-tablas-a-la-vez-sql-server

Comment: configura la relacion entre las tablas en mysql para que al eliminar la primera esta elimine los contenidos relacionados, esto porque hasta donde se, en un delete no aplica ningún JOIN, por otro lado si no te queda de otra, pasa la lista de tablas en un array y mediante un bucle for por ejemplo, ejecuta la query tantas veces como tablas tengas en tu array, aunque la mejor manera seria como te indique modificar tus tablas asignando las relaciones necesarias tanto para udate en cascada como para los deletes si aplica.

Comment: Lo más fiable sería que hagas una sentencia de delete por cada tabla desde el nivel más bajo de relación. Una vez listas las sentencias de delete deberías ponerlas dentro de una [Transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html). Para invocar esto desde PHP u otro lenguaje habría que ponerlo en un Procedimiento Almacenado o una Función.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prueba utilizando transacciones:

```
START TRANSACTION;
   DELETE FROM tabla1;
   DELETE FROM tabla2;
   DELETE FROM tabla3;
   DELETE FROM tabla4;
   DELETE FROM tabla5;
COMMIT;
```

Esto borraría los registros de 5 tablas en una misma ejecución.

Nota: MySQL Administrator a veces no lo reconoce. Pero si phpMyAdmin. Si lo ejecutas con php igual lo ejecutará.

Comment: Gracias por su apoyo, lo tuve que resolver poniendo una consulta por delete y llamando cada una de las consultas

Comment: De nada, lo bueno es aprender más cada día, suerte.
Espero te sirva para futuras consultas jeje.